# Custom link function in scikitlearn

Tags: scikit-learn, glm

R has the option to define and use custom link function in the following way (binomial can be replaced with poisson, etc):

```
link <- function() {
define link, linkinv, d(linkinv)/d(eta)
...
}
model <- glm(y~x, family=binomial(link=link))
```

Is there an equivalent in sklearn where we can define and use custom link functions? I'm particularly keen on regularized implementation like lasso. R's glm function lacks regularization and glmnet does not allow custom link functions.